# Java8: collecting a stream into a SortedMap by key

Tags: java, collections, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

I want to collect a stream into a Map where has the keys sorted, so I tried :

```
TreeMap<LocalDate, MenuChart2.Statistics> last3MPerDay =    

                menuPriceByDayService.findAllOrderByUpdateDate(menu, DateUtils.quarterlyDate(), 92)
                .stream()
                .sorted(comparing(MenuPriceByDay::getUpdateDate))
                .collect(Collectors
                        .toMap(MenuPriceByDay::getUpdateLocalDate, p -> new MenuChart2().new Statistics( p.getMinPrice().doubleValue(),
```

But I got a compilation error

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<LocalDate,Object> to 
 TreeMap<LocalDate,MenuChart2.Statistics>
```

Comment: You'll need to use the overloaded [`toMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-) that accepts a map supplier.

Comment: Please show your compilation error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are storing your data in a sorted map, like a `TreeMap`, you don't need to create a `.sorted()` version of the stream; the collector will naturally sort the data as it stores it in the `TreeMap`.

Your `.collect()` call must return a `TreeMap` in order for the result to be assigned to a `TreeMap`, so `Collectors.toMap()` must take a supplier that creates a `TreeMap` for the collector, to allow the propagation of the required type.

Eg)

```
jshell> String[] data = { "apple", "pear", "orange", "cherry" };
data ==> String[4] { "apple", "pear", "orange", "cherry" }

jshell> var map = Arrays.stream(data)
   ...>                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s,
   ...>                                           s -> s.length(),
   ...>                                           (a,b) -> a,
   ...>                                           TreeMap::new));
map ==> {apple=5, cherry=6, orange=6, pear=4}
```

The resulting `TreeMap` shows the data is sorted by key.

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<LocalDate, MenuChart2.Statistics> last3MPerDay =    

                menuPriceByDayService.findAllOrderByUpdateDate(menu, DateUtils.quarterlyDate(), 92)
                .stream()
                .sorted(comparing(MenuPriceByDay::getUpdateDate))
                .collect(Collectors
                        .toMap(MenuPriceByDay::getUpdateLocalDate, p -> new MenuChart2().new Statistics( p.getMinPrice().doubleValue());

TreeMap<LocalDate, , MenuChart2.Statistics> last3MPerDaySorted = new TreeMap<LocalDate, MenuChart2.Statistics>(last3MPerDay);
```